# Checking Wifi NVS data

Tags: flash, memory, wifi, esp32

Here is my case :

Wifi NVS FLash is enabled.
I am using esp_wifi_get_config to find out whether wifi configuration is saved in NVS. My code is :

```
wifi_config_t conf;
 ret = esp_wifi_get_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &conf);
if (ret == ESP_OK)
    {

  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Wifi configuration already stored in flash partition called NVS");
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s" ,conf.sta.ssid);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s" ,conf.sta.password);
    }
else
    {

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Wifi configuration not found in flash partition called NVS.");    
    configure_wifi();
    }
```

It worked as expected. Then I erased and then initialized my nvs using nvs_flash_erase(); nvs_flash_init(); before the above written code. Now my output is

```
I (697) Wifi station: Wifi configuration already stored in flash partition called NVS

I (707) Wifi station:

I (707) Wifi station:
```

Is my approach right? If not, then what is the correct way to check Wifi nvs data before configuring wifi?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem to find out that it's not possible to check the success of loading wifi_config from the nvs with checking the return value.

I solved the problem by checking the string length of the data coming from the NVS which is typically filled up with 0xff after erasing the flash.

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config;
esp_wifi_get_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_config);

//You could check if more values are set but I figured out that only ssid
//or password is necessary to check against
if(strlen(&wifi_config.sta.ssid) == 0 || strlen(&wifi_config.sta.password) == 0) {
    //do here your error handling
} else {
    //use sucessfully retreived wifi_config
    esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
}
```

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to retrieve the ssid and password from nvs after the wifi provisioning service completes? I tried using nvs_get_str, but get gibberish. I'm having a hard time figuring out what namespace to use in nvs_get_str - is it "nvs.net80211"?